# Separate icon versions for action bar and home screen

Tags: android, android-layout, icons

is it possible to display different versions of the app icon in the app's action bar and on the home screen?

I'm using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` attribute in the `<application>` element of the manifest xml file.

There are currently no customizations in styles.xml files for the AppTheme style or its parent styles.

I've written a couple of Android apps (trying to update one of them) and I'm still not very comfortable with some of the UI specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the `android:logo` attribute of the `<application>` element in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="..."
    android:label="..."
    android:theme="..."
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_actionbar_logo">
```